# Solution to overshadowing by WPF controls

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, kinect, kinect-sdk, xbox

I am trying to find a way around 'The Airspace Problem' concerning implementation of WPF controls.

I am using Kinect Xbox 360, SDK v1.8 and WPF application(Visual C#).

In the XAML file, I have implemented a web browser control within Kinect Region. When I run the application, the web browser overshadows the Kinect region.

I wish to show the cursor movement on the web browser page. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please make sure you have read the [help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) which explain how to ask a good question. Currently, you have not provided a [mcve] so that we can answer your question.

Comment: MahApps have a useful wiki entry which might help: https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/wiki/FAQ#why-is-windowsformshost-and-webbrowser-flickering